# Use of caching in REST

Tags: rest, caching

In a RESTful api, a request like GET /api/resources/resourceID can be cached. But the next time, when the same resource is accessed, the cached value should be returned only to the owner of the resource (i.e request needs to be authorized). Is it possible to make use of this caching and still provide the data only to authorized users ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include the identity of the user in the cache key. Let's say a resource is different depending upon whether or not a user is logged in. An example of cache keys (there are many ways to format them):

```
For non-logged in:
"resource:{resourceID}" (if you are storing more than just resources)
"{resourceID}" (if your cache stores only resources)

For logged-in user:
"resource:{resourceID}:{userID}" or "{resourceID}:{userID}"
```

You need to choose a separator (":" in this case) that cannot show up in any of your data.

Another thing to think about is how you age things out of the queue -- you don't want to end up with cache misses because your cache is filled with user-specific data that will never be used again.